# where is the backlight in laptop screen, physically?

Tags: backlight, laptop-display

if I were to take laptop screen apart, would the backlight be a long, thin gadget along one of the edges, like maybe the bottom edge of the screen? Or is "backlight" actually a matrix of light emitting elements throughout the screen surface?

Comment: I really want to recommend http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiejNAUwcQ8 , where a TFT is disassembled with explanations in a _very_ pedagogical fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer laptops have LED lights throughout the rear surface, but older laptops have a CCFL fluorescent tube along an edge.  I think it is usually along the bottom edge, allowing heat to rise out through the top.

[There's a wikipedia page all about it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlight)

Comment: If its an old school CCFL bulb, [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Replace-Your-Laptop-s-Backlight/?ALLSTEPS) talks about it - in effect its a REALLY small florescent bulb.

Comment: thanks. I guess the article was not very clear about what this stuff physically looks like.

Comment: Depends on the screen basically